# How to add CardView In Center With LinearLayout

Tags: android

How to add CardView In Center With LinearLayout

`activity_main.xml:`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/image">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/simpleSpinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:numeric="integer"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:hint="Enter phone number"
              />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonOTP"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="        Send OTP         " />
    </LinearLayout>
```

`custom_spinner_items.xml`

```
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        
        
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" /><!--Make sure image is present in Drawable folder-->
        
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
        
                android:text="Enter phone number"
                android:textColor="#000" />
        
        </LinearLayout>
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VObBB.jpg) is how the screen appears

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pI7lt.jpg) is how the screen appears without  `android:background="@drawable/image"`

But when I use `android:layout_marginTop="250dp"`for CardView. I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hmo2G.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/image">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/simpleSpinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:numeric="integer"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:hint="Enter phone number"
              />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonOTP"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="        Send OTP         " />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Change the parent LinearLayout to RelativeLayout then make centerInParent = true in the CardView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `match_parent` for your Root layout height instead of `wrap_content` and instead of `android:layout_gravity="center"` use `android:gravity="center"`

Copy below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/image">
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center">
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/simpleSpinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:hint="Enter phone number" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonOTP"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Send OTP" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your viewgroup linearlayout, change the attribute **android:layout_gravity="center"** to **android:gravity="center"**

The attribute **android:layout_gravity** is used to specify how the gravity of a view itself aligns within its parent

The attribute **android:gravity** is used to specify how a parent view should position its children or content

since you want the contents of linearlayout to be centered within itself. use **android:gravity**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/image">
    
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
         <!-- your card view content -->
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonOTP"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="330dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send OTP" />

</LinearLayout>
```